# IndexError: index out of bound (Pandas)

Tags: python, pandas

***I'm getting a error on Pandas please help

```
df.reset_index(drop=True)
ind = list(df[df['BasePay'] == 0.0].index)
df.drop(df.index[ind])
```

And the error output is -

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-88-9ca6ffe769c8> in <module>
      1 df.reset_index(drop=True)
      2 ind = list(df[df['BasePay'] == 0.0].index)
----> 3 df.drop(df.index[ind])

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py in __getitem__(self, key)
   4289 
   4290         key = com.values_from_object(key)
-> 4291         result = getitem(key)
   4292         if not is_scalar(result):
   4293             return promote(result)

IndexError: index 148043 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 148043
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Working on this Dataset

```
https://www.kaggle.com/kaggle/sf-salaries
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly you are trying to drop rows where 'BasePay' column is 0.0.
You can simply do this using [boolean indexing](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html) in order to keep the rows you want like this:

```
newDF = df[df['BasePay'] != 0.0]
```